# Python embedded exception handling

Tags: python, exception

I have a code sample below, where I want to catch some exception:

in the main function:

```
try:
    ...
    do_something()
except some_exception,e:
    do_some_other_thing
```

in the `do_something` function

```
try:
    ...
except some_exception,e:
    do_some_other_thing
```

So when I was testing it, I noticed that the exception was handled twice (once in `do_somthing()`, and once in the `main` function), is my observation accurate?

Is there a way to catch the exception that are only not captured by its function? Because there are two scenarios that I want to catch and they are somewhat wrapped into the same exception handling class(i.e. `some_exception`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is inaccurate; there must be 2 places that raise `some_exeption`, or you are explicitly re-raising it.

Once an exception has correctly been caught, it will not be caught by other handlers higher up in the stack.

This is easiest shown with a little demonstration:

```
>>> try:
...     try:
...         raise AttributeError('foo')
...     except AttributeError as e:
...         print 'caught', e
... except AttributeError as e:
...     print 'caught the same exception again?', e
... 
caught foo
```

Only the *inner* `except` handler was invoked. If, on the other hand, we re-raise the exception, you'll see both handlers print a message:

```
>>> try:
...     try:
...         raise AttributeError('foo')
...     except AttributeError as e:
...         print 'caught', e
...         raise e
... except AttributeError as e:
...     print 'caught the same exception again?', e
... 
caught foo
caught the same exception again? foo
```

As such, there is no need to have to handle 'exceptions that are not caught by the function'; you will *only* need to handle exceptions that were not already caught earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try it out and see what happens with a simple test?

```
def main():
    try:
        raise ValueError("in main!")
    except ValueError as e:
        print "caught exception",str(e)
        #for fun, re-run with the next line uncommented and see what happens!
        #raise

try:
    main()
except ValueError:
    print "caught an exception above main"
```

If you actually try this code, you'll notice that it only prints one message (inside the `main` function) demonstrating that an exception will not propagate upward once caught (unless you re-`raise` it in your except clause).